# Splitting the file based on first character of word

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I want to split the file based on the 1st Character of the word and create output files based on the 1st character.
I am doing...

```
awk '{print > substr($0, 1, 1)}' "$File"
```

But the `awk` is giving `'fatal: expression for >' redirection has null string value'`.
The file contains some blank lines.
How do I ignore the blank lines while I do the split.

The content of $File is

```
100009-01  -- This should go in file named 1
200009-01  -- This should go in file named 2
300009-01  -- This should go in file named 3
400009-01
500009-01
600037-01
700037-01
800037-01
900037-01
100037-01  -- This should go in file named 1
A0037-02_  -- This should go in file named A
a00037-02  -- This should go in file named a
c00037-02
B00037-02
200037-02
```

It should generate the file named **"1"** and all the lines that are starting with 1 should go into this file.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you have `'>'` at all?  Remove it. E.g. `awk '{print substr($0,1,1)}' file`

Comment: Are you looking to create an output file from `awk` program? If yes then only you need redirection. And if redirection(output file needed) is needed then better post samples of input and expected output also in your question, thank you.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13: Yes I have to create output file

Comment: @NJMR, Thanks for clarifying that, could you please post samples of input and output in your question also to get a better picture of question, thank you.

Comment: `awk '{c=substr($0,1,1); if (c!=" "&&c!="\t"&&c!="") print c > "newfile"}' file` will write the first non-blank character of each line to `newfile`.

Comment: Just add the `/./` pattern before your `{...}` block to select only non-empty lines.

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples, please try following `awk` code.

```
sort -k1.1 Input_file | 
awk '
!NF{ next }
{
  currentFile=substr($1,1,1)
}
prev!=currentFile{
  close(prev)
}
{
  print > (currentFile)
  prev=currentFile
}
'
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
sort -k1.1 Input_file |         ##Sorting Input_file with 1st letter to make it easier for awk.
awk '                           ##Sending output to awk program as an input.
!NF{ next }                     ##If its an empty line then move to next line.
{
  currentFile=substr($1,1,1)    ##Setting currentFile to 1st letter of current line.
}
prev!=currentFile{              ##If prev is NOT equal to currentFile then do following.
  close(prev)                   ##Closing prev file in backend to avoid errors.
}
{
  print > (currentFile)         ##Printing current line into currentFile output file.
  prev=currentFile              ##Setting currentFile value to prev here.
}
'
```

Comment: I would use `$1` instead of `$0` in `substr($0,1,1)`, to make sure to not create white-space filenames. That's not a requirement though

Comment: @RavinderSingh13: The file is already sorted and the size of the file is in 20+GB.

Comment: @NJMR, this file is sorted with 1st letter, which it doesn't show in your samples, sorting it will make it easier to process and closing files in backend. Hence I sorted it with 1st letter or so, let me know once you run it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how it could be done with bash:

```sh
while read -r line; do
    echo "$line" >> "${line:0:1}"
done < "$File"
```

Answer (score 0):

> The file contains some blank lines. How do I ignore the blank lines
> while I do the split.

If this is sole problem you might simply fix your code following way:

```
awk '$0!=""{print > substr($0, 1, 1)}' "$File"
```

Explanation: I added condition to your action, which is true if whole line (`$0`) is not equal (`!=`) empty string (`""`), therefore empty lines will be ignored.

Comment: You would still have the error with non-blank lines that started with blank (or illegal) characters...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a minor update to your original code:

```
awk 'NF{print > substr($1, 1, 1)}' "$File"
```

Since `awk` works with `(pattern){action}` rules, it implies that `action` is taken when `pattern` is non-zero or non-empty. The value of `NF` gives the total number of fields in your current record (line). By using `NF` as the `pattern`, awk will perform the action if the current line contains non-space characters.

Besides that, we also use `$1` instead of `$0`. This is just to avoid that there are lines that could start with a space and we use the first character of the first field.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to put this into one shell script, but you can base yourself on following:

```
cut -c 1 test.txt | sort | uniq
```

This gives the list of the first characters, present in your file (it also gives you the filenames you're about to create).

```
grep "^1" test.txt
```

This gives you all the lines of your file, starting with "1".

Take care: don't use `a>file` because this will always delete and recreate your file. I propose you do `a>>file`, which creates the files in case of non-existing and appends otherwise.

So, in pseudocode, you should get something like:

```
foreach (char a in $(cut -c 1 test.txt | sort | uniq))
{
  grep "^$a" test.txt >>$a
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple `awk` would be:

```
awk '/^[^[:blank:]]/{
    fn=substr($0,1,1)
    if (fn in seen)
        print >>(fn)
    else
        print >(fn)
    close(fn)
    seen[fn]
}' file
```

You can test it:

```
a=( $(cut -c 1 file | sort | uniq) )
head $(printf "%s " "${a[@]}")
==> 1 <==
100009-01  -- This should go in file named 1
100037-01  -- This should go in file named 1

==> 2 <==
200009-01  -- This should go in file named 2
200037-02

==> 3 <==
300009-01  -- This should go in file named 3

==> 4 <==
400009-01

==> 5 <==
500009-01

==> 6 <==
600037-01

==> 7 <==
700037-01

==> 8 <==
800037-01

==> 9 <==
900037-01

==> A <==
a00037-02  -- This should go in file named a

==> B <==
B00037-02

==> a <==
a00037-02  -- This should go in file named a

==> c <==
c00037-02
```

Note: This is on a Mac so the file `A` is the same as the file `a`...